# constructing npda from given language| how

Tags: math, compiler-construction, discrete-mathematics

I have  following language over the alphabet {1,0}
L = {w | every prefix of w has no more 1's than 0's}

**How** can I construct an NPDA M from G such that L(M) = L(G)?
Or 
To do that conversion, can one recommend any webpage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, the way to construct an NPDA for languages is just to find the grammar since the mapping between a CFG and NPDAs is rather simple.

The CFG (Context free grammar) for such a language would be something like

```
S -> S "0" S | "" | S "0" S "1" S | S "1" S "0" S
```

Once you have a context free grammar, building a NPDA of it should be relativly simple ;)

btw, You have not mentioned what is G in your above post so I assumed you wanted an explanation of how to construct an NPDA for the described language. If you meant something else, tell me and I'll update me explanation.